# throwing errors in express functional routes

Tags: node.js, express, functional-programming

I'm trying to work with pure functional route controller functions and I have an express route controller:

```
router.get('/', serveJson((x, y) => (x > 5 ? {
  x: x + y
} : WHAT)))
```

`serveBody` is a middleware that provides the params `x` and `y` for the handler function and does the regular `res.json(...)`.
What should be instead of `WHAT` to make the controller throw out an error? Or is there a different way to throw errors in functional code?
I tried `throw "x should be smaller than 5"` but that doesn't work and doesn't fell right.

Answer (score 1):

> Or is there a different way to throw errors in functional code?

Well throwing errors is a side-effect and so entirely non-functional. However, express makes use of them to get the server to respond in certain ways, so it's a little out of your control. You will have to `throw` at some point...

I agree the "trick" is to write a dynamic route handler, but I think I would change it a bit from how @eol wrote theirs

1. the `x > 5` code is part of your lambda in your route, but the Error message `x should be greater than 5` is non-configurable. If the lambda changes to say `x > 6`, the error message wouldn't make sense
2. the single-branch `if` statement is wonky and requiring `undefined` for the unused branch is a wart in the code. Maybe move the `Error` to this position?

Here's what a revised handler might look like -

```
const serveJson = (cb) => (req, res, next) => {
  const x = Number(req.query.x)
  const y = Number(req.query.y)
  const data = cb(x, y)

  if (data instanceof Error)
    throw data 
  else
    res.json(data)
}

app.get('/test', serveJson((x, y) =>
  x > 5
    ? { x: x + y }
    : Error(`value for x (${x}) cannot exceed 5`)
))
```

Still issues remain. `serveJson` is not suitably generic as it always queries `x` and `y` parameters, making us question why it's a separate function at all. How many routes will you need to define that specifically read only the `x` and `y` request parameters?

Would you use it like this? I don't know, it feels like a reach -

```
app.get('/add', serveJson((x, y) =>
  x > 5
    ? { result: x + y }
    : Error(`value for x (${x}) cannot exceed 5`)
))

app.get('/mult', serveJson((x, y) =>
  x > 10
    ? { result: x * y }
    : Error(`value for x (${x}) cannot exceed 10`)
))

app.get('/divide', serveJson((x, y) =>
  x !== 0
    ? { result: x / y }
    : Error(`divisor cannot be zero`)
))
```

Are you really going to have lots of places where you can use `serveJson` like this? It seems unlikely, but to beat a dead horse, let's try making `serveJson` more flexible by letting us specify the params we want to work with. That'll fix it, right?

```
const serveJson = (params, cb) => (req, res, next) => {
  const data = cb(...params.map(p => Number(req.query[p])))
  if (data instanceof Error)
    throw data 
  else
    res.json(data)
}

app.get('/test', serveJson(['x', 'y'], (x, y) =>
  x > 5
    ? { result: x + y }
    : Error(`value for x (${x}) cannot exceed 5`)
))
```

This would be considered more functional because all of the inter-related parts are configurable arguments at the `serveJson` call site. But you still have a huge problem - it assumes all parameters are numbers and attempts to parse/validate them accordingly.

Sure, you could keep working at this and come up with something -

```
app.get('/test/, serveJson({ x: Number, y: Number, z: String }, (x, y, z) =>
  // ...
))
```

But notice how all of the external specification is getting big. It's as if it would be easier to skip `serveJson` altogether. No hidden intentions with 100% flexibility -

```
app.get('/test', (req, res, next) => {
  const x = Number (req.params.x)
  const y = Number (req.params.y)
  if (x > 5)
    res.json({ result: x + y })
  else
    throw Error(`value for x (${x}) cannot exceed 5`)
})
```

At the end of all of this, you asked for a magic bullet that simply cannot exist. At least not when you start to imagine non-trivial cases, unlike the pseudocode provided in your OP.

Please share more context around your entire program. I think everyone will be able to help you more effectively.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is return e.g. `null` or `undefined` and handle this result in your `serveJson` middleware. Something like this:

```
const serveJson = (cb) => {
    return function (req, res, next) {
        // TODO: Validate input
        const x = Number.parseInt(req.query.x);
        const y = Number.parseInt(req.query.y);

        const result = cb(x, y);
        if (typeof res === 'undefined') {
            throw new Error("x should be greater than 5");
        }
        res.json({ result });
    }

};

app.get('/test', serveJson((x, y) => (x > 5 ? { x: x + y } : undefined)));
```

If you now call `/test?x=6&y=3`, you'll get

```
{"result":{"x":9}}
```

If you call `/test?x=3&y=3`, you'll get the error:

```
Error: x should be greater than 5
```

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing is relying on a contract between the route handler and the `serveJson` wrapper. I return an object like this:

```
{
  body: "X should be greater than 5",
  status: 400
}
```

`serveJson` is checking the `status` field, if it's 400 it throws an exception for the express middleware to handle.

---

The route handler looks like this:

```
app.get('/test', serveJson((x, y) => (x > 5 ? { body: "1234", status: 200 } : {
  body: "X should be greater than 5",
  status: 400
})));
```

And `serveJson`:

```
const serveJson = (cb) => {
    return function (req, res, next) {
        const result = cb({req.query);
        if (result.status === 400) {
            throw new Error(result.body);
        }
        res.json({ result });
    }
};
```

This way the route handler is a pure function getting params and in case of input error it responds by the contract with `status: 400`.